# Python:- Extracting the column headers from rows[0] enclosed in a <th> tag. Remove the unicode symbol and the link number after the planet name

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to iterate over all the column headers of row[0] then remove the unicode symbol
and the link number after the planet name. Right now my code looks like this:-

```py
URL_solar_system = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_gravitationally_rounded_objects_of_the_Solar_System"

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

html_content = requests.get(URL_solar_system).text

soup_solar = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")

tables = soup_solar.find_all('table', attrs={'class': 'wikitable'})

planets = tables[2]

rows = planets.find_all('tr')

headers = [th.text.strip() for th in rows[0].find_all('th') if th.get_text().strip() != '' ] 

print('headers: {}'.format(headers))
```

OUTPUT

```
headers: ['*Mercury[6][7]', '*Venus[8][9]', '*Earth[10][11]', '*Mars[12][13]', '°Jupiter[14][15]', '°Saturn[16][17]', '‡Uranus[18][19]', '‡Neptune[20][21]']
```

I am trying to achieve the output as shown below.
Desired Output:

```
headers: ['Mercury', 'Venus', 'Earth', 'Mars', 'Jupiter', 'Saturn', 'Uranus', 'Neptune']
```

Hint for writing the code:-

1. headers = []
2. for loop that will loop through row[0] with a find all on 'th'
3. first_variable = uses your iterator (let's say we call it i in the for loop definition) and uses the text method on it
4. second_variable = find this value '[' from the first variable that has the text method
   redefine the first variable by indexing the second element to the second variable element you defined.
5. if statement for that label where is appends the first variable to the headers list you created.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
import re # in the begining of your module
```

then just add to the end of your code the following line

```
headers = re.findall(r'(\w+)\[\d+]',''.join(headers))
```

Your final code

```
import re

URL_solar_system = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_gravitationally_rounded_objects_of_the_Solar_System"

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

html_content = requests.get(URL_solar_system).text

soup_solar = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")

tables = soup_solar.find_all('table', attrs={'class': 'wikitable'})

planets = tables[2]

rows = planets.find_all('tr')

headers = [th.text.strip() for th in rows[0].find_all('th') if th.get_text().strip() != '' ] 

headers = re.findall(r'(\w+)\[\d+]',''.join(headers))

print('headers: {}'.format(headers))
```

Comment: I have modified the anser where we need `import re` in the begining of your modue, in order to use regular expresion.

Answer (score 0):

The header text are `href`'s under the fourth table. Try using a CSS Selector that selects the fourth table: `table:nth-of-type(4)`, and then use `th > a` which selects the `a` tags (the headers) under the `th` tags.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_gravitationally_rounded_objects_of_the_Solar_System"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL).content, "html.parser")

print([tag.text for tag in soup.select("table:nth-of-type(4) th > a")])
```

Output:

```
['Mercury', 'Venus', 'Earth', 'Mars', 'Jupiter', 'Saturn', 'Uranus', 'Neptune']
```